# If $X$ has non-singular normalization $\dim (\mathrm{Sing(X)})=\dim (X)-1$?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, normalization

Let $X\subseteq\mathbb{P}^{N}$ be a quasiprojective variety of dimension $N-1$, and let 
$$
\nu:X^{\nu}\rightarrow X
$$
be its normalization. Let us suppose that $X^{\nu}(\neq X)$ is smooth. I wonder if in this case
$$
\dim (\mathrm{Sing(X)})=\dim (X)-1.
$$
I think Serre's Normality Criterion (See Lemma 12.5 of [this](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/download/properties.pdf) text) has something to do with it, but I can't see how.

Maybe
$$
X^{\nu} \text{ smooth }\Rightarrow
$$
$$
\Rightarrow
 X\text{ satisfies the property $(S_{2})$ (i.e. $\forall$ $x\in X, \mathrm{depth}(\mathcal{O}_{X,x})\geq \min\{2,\dim(\mathcal{O}_{X,x})\}$)},
$$
in which case the equality follows from the fact that $X$ is reduced, not normal, and would satisfy $(R_{1})$ if 
$$
\dim (\mathrm{Sing(X)})<\dim (X)-1.
$$
Is that implication true? At least, is the equality true?

Comment: You should get a counterexample from taking any projective variety and gluing two points.

Comment: @dhy I made a similar comment, but then noticed that the first line stipulates $X$ is a hypersurface; I'm not sure such a gluing can be embedded as one.

Comment: I believe it is true for hypersurfaces, or any Cohen Macaulay variety.

Comment: It can't, the S2 requirement on the hypersurface actually forces the conductor ideal to be pure codimension 1.  I'll explain in an answer.

Comment: see page 186 of hartshorne: https://books.google.com/books?id=3rtX9t-nnvwC&pg=PA186&lpg=PA186&dq=a+cohen+macaulay+variety+is+normal+if+and+only+if+non+singular+in+codimension+one&source=bl&ots=XP4e6HIEk5&sig=eIUHub1rr8uBFbSLJ_oAm9ZEVuQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiC09Ll-p_LAhUG4WMKHaQIBVsQ6AEILzAC#v=onepage&q=a%20cohen%20macaulay%20variety%20is%20normal%20if%20and%20only%20if%20non%20singular%20in%20codimension%20one&f=false

Comment: @Mark Indeed, I didn't see that...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Proposition:**  *If $X$ is S2, then the normalization map $\nu : X^{n} \to X$ is an isomorphism outside a set of pure codimension 1 (in either $X$ or $X^{n}$).*

*Proof:*  Let $Z \subseteq X$ be the locus where $\nu$ is not an isomorphism and let $W \subseteq X^{n}$ be the (scheme-theoretic) pre-image of $W$.  For a contradiction, by localizing at the generic point of a component of $Z$, one may assume that $Z$ is of codimension $\geq 2$.  Let $i : U = X \setminus Z \hookrightarrow X$ and $j : V = X^{n} \setminus W \hookrightarrow X^{n}$.  Then since $X$ is S2, $$i_* O_U = O_X \text{ and } j_* O_V = O_{X^n}.$$ 
But $O_U = O_V$ and so $$\nu_* O_{X^n} = \nu_* j_* O_V = i_* O_U = O_X.$$ Hence $X$ is normal.

#### In your case...

Now, since hypersurfaces are S2 (even Cohen-Macaulay), the locus where the normalization map is not an isomorphism pure codimension 1 as you desired.